# Swift - How do you cast a CVImageBufferRef as a CVPixelBufferRef

Tags: swift

In objective-c you can easily cast a CVImageBufferRef as a CVPixelBufferRef:

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = some value

CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
```

How can I do this in swift?

---

```
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
```

gives the error: 'Unmanaged<CVPixelBufferRef>' is not convertible to 'CVPixelBufferRef'

---

```
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer).takeRetainedValue()
```

gives the error: 'CVImageBuffer' is not convertible to 'CVPixelBufferRef'

---

```
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer).takeRetainedValue() as CVPixelBufferRef
```

gives the error: Cannot convert the expression's type 'CVPixelBufferRef' to type 'CVPixelBufferRef'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT**

This answer was given during Swift beta test period. It seems that now the solution is simpler, as suggested by klinger

```
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
```

however I'll leave the previous answer for historycal reasons :-)

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

Look at the prerelease docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_40

Specifically this statement

> Remapped Types
>
> When Swift imports Core Foundation types, the compiler remaps the
>   names of these types. The compiler removes Ref from the end of each
>   type name because all Swift classes are reference types, therefore the
>   suffix is redundant.
>
> The Core Foundation CFTypeRef type completely remaps to the AnyObject
>   type. Wherever you would use CFTypeRef, you should now use AnyObject
>   in your code.

The first thing you would like to do, is to remove the "ref" from each type.
However it's not necessary, since the "refs" are typealiased to the "non-ref" types.

Then, this statement should work. It may need some tuning before I've never worked with `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer`, and for this reason I'm not sure about the first line (initialize the buffer)

```
    var buf : CMSampleBuffer = // initialize the buffer
    var anUnmanaged : Unmanaged<CVImageBuffer> = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buf)
    var returnValue = anUnmanaged.takeUnretainedValue()
```

Or, shortly

```
    var buf : CMSampleBuffer = // initialize the buffer
    var anUnmanaged : CVImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buf).takeRetainedValue()
```

However, you asked for a CVPixelBuffer. 
If the two types are fully compatible (I don't know the underlying API so I assume that casting between CVPixelBuffer and CVImageBuffer in objc is always safe), there is no "automatism" to do it, you have to pass through an Unsafe Pointer.

The complete code is this:

```
    var buf : CMSampleBuffer = // initialize the buffer
    var anUnmanaged : Unmanaged<CVImageBuffer> = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buf)
    var returnValue = anUnmanaged.takeUnretainedValue()

    var anOpaque = anUnmanaged.toOpaque()
    var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer = Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.fromOpaque(anOpaque).takeUnretainedValue()
```

I used takeUnretainedValue() that doesn't consume a retain count, since CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer() returns an unretained object

Comment: Thank you! In objective-c CVImageBufferRef is a synonym for a CVPixelBufferRef, so this was driving me crazy.

Comment: In this case I suggest you to file a bug-feature request to have an automatic cast in a future release :-) I don't exclude that there is some function to bridge between the two types hidden somewhere, however passing through an opaque pointer is the first solution that came to my mind :-)

Comment: Using from an objective C library in swift. Now i understand why i was getting crash when trying to convert.                                                                                              This is useful when a function returns an unmanaged reference and you know that you're not responsible for releasing the result.

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 6 beta 6 this finally works:

`var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)`

Answer (score 1):

@LombaX's solution didn't work for me in the latest build, Xcode Beta5. Here's what did work:

```
let imageBuffer : CVImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
let srcPtr = Unmanaged.passUnretained(imageBuffer).toOpaque()
let pixelBuffer = Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.fromOpaque(srcPtr).takeUnretainedValue()
```